# Octave - show "real' zero

Tags: octave

Sometimes Octave shows a number that is very close to zero, instead of "real" zero.

e.g.:

```
>> sin(pi)
ans =   1.2246e-016
```

I understand that it's due to floating point arithmetic problems, and so on, but it's annoying...

Is there a way to get the expected `0` instead of some almost-zero value?

## EDIT

A more real-life example is this:

```
>> cos(pi) + i*sin(pi)
ans = -1.0000e+000 + 1.2246e-016i
```

Applying some rounding function to the result won't help, and I don't want to insert rounding functions inside the calculation.

Isn't some way to tell Octave "to be less precise"?

Other, less sophisticated tools (like SpeedCrunch) do it "out-of-the-box":

```
cos(pi) + i*sin(pi)
= -1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GNU Octave, round a number to units precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386033/gnu-octave-round-a-number-to-units-precision)

Answer (score 3):

Its a bit ambiguous to define

> very close to zero

But however you can use  round function, which rounds to nearest integer

```
round(sin(pi))
```

Of course this will not work with sin function as the all return values are between [-1 1].

So you can define your generic function to truncate the number if the it is less than a certain range.

```
function retval = bound (num,boundval)

  if  (abs(num) < boundval)
    retval = 0;
  else
    retval = num;
  endif
endfunction
```

This function will set return zero if the num argument is in range of [-bound     bound]

You can use it for example as

`bound(myvar,0.001);`